# Spring JPA removing @OneToOne relationship

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a SpringBoot 2.1.3.RELEASE RESTful Web Service app., using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file, I have this object:

```
public class ImpactHint implements Serializable {



    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "impactHint", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "IA_ID")
    private ImpactHintAmendment amendment ;


...

}
```

and also

```
public class ImpactHintAmendment implements Serializable, IEntity<String> {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "IA_ID")
    private ImpactHint impactHint;  
..
}
```

I am trying to remove, using

```
em.remove(impactHint.getAmendment());
em.persist(impactHint);
```

and also

```
impactHint.setAmendment(null);
em.persist(impactHint);
```

in my repository class, but nothing works

```
@Repository
public class ImpactHintDao extends AbstractDao<ImpactHint, String> implements IImpactHintDao {


    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

   ..
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For OneToOne bi-directional use the `mappedBy` attribute to define inverse mapping. The owning entity ImpactHint uses `@JoinColumn` and has FK column. Second entity:

```
public class ImpactHintAmendment {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "amendment")
    private ImpactHint impactHint;
```

If you correct your mapping, then orphan removal attr. should remove `Amendment` without calling remove

```
impactHint.setAmendment(null);
em.persist(impactHint);
```